# what is the meaning of ほっくり?

Tags: words

Sentence in question:
ほっくりしていて香りもきつくなく、おいしいですよ。

I cant find a translation for ほっくり on jisho.org. Anyone here who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **ほっくりして**いて香りもきつくなく、おいしいですよ。

You can think of it as a variant of the onomatopoeia 「ほくほく」...

<sub>Examples of this kind of variants: ふんわり - ふわふわ, びっしょり - びしょびしょ, がっちり - がちがち, もっちり - もちもち, こっそり - こそこそ, ぼんやり - ぼやぼや, じんわり - じわじわ, etc... these pairs have almost the same meaning, if not always interchangeable.</sub>

ほっくり / ほくほく mean:

> ほっくり〘副詞<sub>ト</sub>〙
>   食べ物があたたかいさま。また、ふかしたての芋などが、水分が少なく味にこくがあるさま。「**ほっくりとした**カボチャの煮物」
>   (明鏡国語辞典)

> ほくほく 〘副詞<sub>ト</sub>〙
>   ② ふかしたての芋などが、水分が少なくて味にこくがあるさま。「**ほくほくした**焼き芋」
>   (明鏡国語辞典)

> ほくほく
>   ２〔煮物などが柔らかくほぐれる様子〕
>   このいもは**ほくほくして**うまい
>   What a good potato! It *has a light, dry texture*.
>   ([プログレッシブ英和中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/70070/meaning/m1u/))

> ほくほく
>   ２ 〈芋などが〉**ほくほくする**
>   *be not soggy and taste very good*.
>   ([研究社新和英中辞典](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%8F%E3%81%BB%E3%81%8F))

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the regional dialect though, I expect something is warm and puffy. As in the last answer probably wrapping up potatoes with an aluminium foil and heat it up, when you eat it, it tastes soft and warm air inflating in your mouth.

Answer (score 2):

[From Kotobank.jp:](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A-673630)

［副］(スル)ほかほかとあたたかく、やわらかいさま。ほくほく。「ほっくり（と）したカボチャ」

Warm, fluffy, and soft.

Various onomatopoeia exist for this word. For examply, ほっかほっか亭 is the name of a fast food chain, which name connotes warm and fluffy products.